# What is different styled(component) and styled(tagname) in performance issues of react?

Tags: reactjs, styled-components

I'm new to styled-components and I was wondering what is different styled(component) and styled(tagname) in performance issues of react.

### styled(tagname)

```js
const StyledP = styled('p')``

export const StyledComponent = props => (
  <StyledP>{props.name}</StyledP>
)
```

[image]

[image]

### styled(component)

```js
const FunctionalComponent = props => (
  <p className={props.className}>{props.name}</p>
)

export const StyledComponent = styled(FunctionalComponent)`
`
```

[image]
[image]

I looked at the this [comment](https://github.com/styled-components/styled-components/issues/1226#issuecomment-335240613)
 and found out if I using `styled(component)`.
but I don't know in performance issues of react.
can someone please explain?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its the same API with a few additional checks in case the target is a component. Extracted from the `styled` constructor [source code](https://github.com/styled-components/styled-components/blob/master/packages/styled-components/src/models/StyledComponent.js#L241) :

```
const isTargetStyledComp = isStyledComponent(target);

// fold the underlying StyledComponent attrs up (implicit extend)
const finalAttrs =
  // $FlowFixMe
  isTargetStyledComp && target.attrs
    ? Array.prototype.concat(target.attrs, attrs).filter(Boolean)
    : attrs;

// fold the underlying StyledComponent rules up (implicit extend)
const componentStyle = new ComponentStyle(
  isTargetStyledComp ? target.componentStyle.rules.concat(rules) : rules,
  finalAttrs,
  styledComponentId
);

// $FlowFixMe
WrappedStyledComponent.foldedComponentIds = isTargetStyledComp
  ? // $FlowFixMe
    Array.prototype.concat(target.foldedComponentIds, target.styledComponentId)
  : EMPTY_ARRAY;

WrappedStyledComponent.target = isTargetStyledComp ? target.target : target;
```

To summarize:

- Extend the attrs and rules of the base styled component with the derived styled component's rules.
- Keep a list of componentIds, in case of nested `styled(Component)` extensions.
- Preserve the original target element (dom string), as the target for all extensions.